# Swift - Calling a func of a UIViewController from a Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2

Here is my problem:

I have a MainTableViewController with an outlet for a table that uses custom UITableViewCells. I also have an outlet for a UIView, called BlackView, in MainTableViewController.

What I want to do: Inside myCustomCell I would like to set "BlackView.hidden = false". I am trying to use "class func" in my MainTableViewController file, and call it from myCustomCell, but it is not working, because Xcode stops recognizing BlackView when I put the word "class" before "func".

So, I would like to call a function of a MainTableViewController or access its outlet from the .swift of my .xib file.

Does anybody knows how to do that?

Here is my .xib file:

[My .xib file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFDwL.png)

Here is the .swift for my .xib file:

```
class myCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var commentTextView: UITextView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {

        commentTextView.delegate = self

        super.awakeFromNib()

    }


    func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {

        MainTableViewController.hideBlackView(true)

    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {

        var comment = commentTextView.text

    }

}
```

Here is my MainTableViewController:

```
class MainTableViewController: UIViewController

    @IBOutlet weak var MyTable: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var BlackView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        BlackView.hidden = true;

        MyTable.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "myCustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCustomCellID")

    }

    class func hideBlackView(setToHidden: Bool) {

        if setToHidden == true {

            BlackView.hidden = true

        } else {

            BlackView.hidden = false

        }


    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCustomCellID") as! PublishHeaderTableViewCell

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None


            return cell


    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 1

    }

}
```

Here is my Main.storyboard:

[My Main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiuJ6.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Answer is Delegation**

BlackView is an instance which will be created by the OS. The outlet is a special property (called an outlet) referencing that instance. When MainTableViewController is shown, an instance of it is created by the OS.

You probably want to use an instance method, not a class method to change the hidden property on instance of BlackView. To do that you will need to pass a reference of the MainTableViewController instance to myCustomCell. This is called **delegation**, which is how ios programming and most MVC models work.

To do this add define a delegate protocol (just above the definition for the custom cell would be normal) and add a weak var to the cell of this type:

```
// use a class protocol for delegates so weak properties can be used
protocol MyCustomCellDelegate: class {
    func hideBlackView(setToHidden: Bool)
}

class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var commentTextView: UITextView!

    weak var delegate: MyCustomCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        commentTextView.delegate = self
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }


    func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
        delegate?.hideBlackView(true)
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
        var comment = commentTextView.text
    }
}
```

Then when you are setting up the cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath, cast as the the proper cell type which should be MyCustomCell in the example you've given not PublishHeaderTableViewCell (also note that I've switched your custom cell class name to starting with a capital letter as is industry standard in ios development). Finally, set the delegate to the instance of the MainTableViewController (which is called "self" from within instance functions).

BTW, in your case, you are only using one cell, so you probably don't need to dequeue and reuse cells. You could just take all that out and return a simple instance you created of the cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Anyway, I will leave all that in place in case you have just simplified your code for Stack Overflow.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // you need to cast the cell to your custom class to use it
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCustomCellID") as! MyCustomCell
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    // set the delegate
    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```

Finally, and VERY IMPORTANTLY, you need to declare that MainTableViewController conforms to the the protocols that will use it so the functions (methods) that other objects want to delegate to it will succeed. In your case it needs to conform to both MyCustomCellDelegate which we wrote above, but also since you are using it for the for the tableView's data source (for cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection) you need to declare that it conforms to UITableViewDataSource (You may have done this already through Interface Builder (story board).. if not you can do it in the class definition).

```
// Declare objects conform to protocols by including protocol names separated by commas after the colon (or the class inherited from) 

class MainTableViewController: UIViewController, MyCustomCellDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var MyTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var BlackView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        BlackView.hidden = true
        MyTable.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "myCustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCustomCellID")
    }

    func hideBlackView(setToHidden: Bool) {
        // since they are both bools just set BlackView.hidden to the setToHidden parameter directly
        BlackView.hidden = setToHidden
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCustomCellID") as! MyCustomCell
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

        // set the delegate
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

As a final note, I'm not sure is setting the delegate for the UITextView is a appropriate in the awakeFromNib method in your custom cell. I know that this method doesn't always fire.. In your case since it is on an outlet, I think it is OK, but I don't use XIB files very much my self, so you may want to print to the console to make sure it is being called each time or research the issue more.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works, now! I just had to make the following changes in your code: 1st: delete "weak" from "weak var delegate: MyCustomCellDelegate?"; 2nd: Delete "class" from "class func hideBlackView(setToHidden: Bool)".

Comment: Nice catch on the need to remove "class". That was a copy paste typo. None of the code above was written or tested in XCode. So there may be other errors. I have updated the code to remove the bug. You shouldn't need to delete the weak from "weak var delegate: MyCustomDelgate?"  Actually, it is bad practice not to have the "weak", because it will keep a strong reference to the object that owns it. This prevents the auto reference counting that deals with memory management behinds the scenes in ios from working.

Comment: I should add that in your case the cells will be destroyed when the references to them which are held by the UITableView are destroyed (when the table goes out of scope). This will almost certainly happen before your UIViewController instance goes out of scope, so in this case it shouldn't cause the dreaded "retain cycle."  You may not have been able to make it weak because I forgot to declare it as a class protocol in my code above, which I have now fixed.