# How to add additional textfields by clicking button in table view

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swift4, swift5

I am trying to add an option to add additional student fields inside table so that user can add more than one student name.

But I am confused how to do it using table view.

**I am not interested in hiding view with specific number of fields.**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {


struct listItems{

    var title : String
    var isExpandable:Bool
    var maxFields :Int

    init(title:String,isExp:Bool,mxF:Int) {

        self.title = title
        self.isExpandable = isExp
        self.maxFields = mxF
    }

    }
@IBOutlet weak var tblListTable: UITableView!


let data : [listItems] = [listItems(title: "Name", isExp: false, mxF: 1), listItems(title: "Student Name", isExp: true, mxF: 20), listItems(title: "Email", isExp: false, mxF: 1)]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tblListTable.delegate = self
    tblListTable.dataSource = self

    self.tblListTable.reloadData()
    print("isLoaded")

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return data.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print("cellForRow")

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! ListCell


    cell.lblName.text = data[indexPath.row].title

    if data[indexPath.row].isExpandable == true {
        cell.btnAddField.isHidden = false
        print("ishidden")
    }
    else {
        cell.btnAddField.isHidden = true
    }


    return cell

}
```

}

**List Cell Class**

```
import UIKit

protocol AddFieldDelegate : class {
   func addField( _ tag : Int)
}

 class ListCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var btnAddField: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var txtField: UITextField!


override func awakeFromNib() {

    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}

func addField( _ tag : Int){



}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Show us what have you done so far.

Comment: okay.. i will edit the question with more details

Comment: @Jaseel.Dev You need to add another object based on your required index at your data array. for eg: `listItems(title: "NickName", isExp: false, mxF: 1)` it should be insert at your index 2 on your data array. Then reload the tableview. I hope you will cleared my point.

Comment: yeah..could you please explain it as the answer with codes..i will mark it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track creating the `AddFieldDelegate`. However, rather than implementing the method inside the `ListCell` class you need to implement it in the `ViewController`.

First, change the view controller class definition line to:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, AddFieldDelegate {
```

This will allow you to call the delegate method from the view controller. Next, when you are creating your table view cells add the line:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

After that, move the method definition of the method `addField` to the view controller.
So inside of your view controller add:

```
func addField(titleOfTextFieldToAdd: String, numberAssociatedWithTextFieldToAdd: Int) {
      data.append(listItems(title: titleOfTextFieldToAdd, isExp: false, mxF: numberAssociatedWithTextFieldToAdd))
      self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I used an example definition of the `addField` method but you can change it to anything that you would like, just make sure that you change the data array and reload the table view data.

Lastly, we must define the delegate in the `ListCell` class. So add this line to the `ListCell` class:

```
weak var delegate: MyCustomCellDelegate?
```

You can then add the text field by running the following anywhere in your `ListCell` class:

```
delegate?.addField(titleOfTextFieldToAdd: "a name", numberAssociatedWithTextFieldToAdd: 50)
```

For more information on delegation, look at the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547041/swift-calling-a-func-of-a-uiviewcontroller-from-a-custom-uitableviewcell) question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to append another item in your data array on button click and reload the tableview.